# How to add hover_data on different traces of same graph

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

```
fig = go.Figure()


fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[0]["ToxPi Score"], name="Suffolk")
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[1]["ToxPi Score"], name="Plymouth")
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[2]["ToxPi Score"], name="Bristol")
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[3]["ToxPi Score"], name="Norfolk")
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[4]["ToxPi Score"], name="Middlesex")
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[5]["ToxPi Score"], name="Worcester")
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[6]["ToxPi Score"], name="Barnstable")
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=alldates, y=countriesData[7]["ToxPi Score"], name="Franklin")


fig.update_xaxes(
rangeslider_visible=True,
rangeselector=dict(
    buttons=list([
        dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(step="all")
    ])
)
)

fig.show()
```

output:- [image]

I have added different traces on same graph using different dataframes. But when i hover on each line it shows only the value of Y.
My question is how do i add more data when i hover over the traces?

P.s i am using different csv of each trace

Comment: I have also used plotly.express for figure, in that case i can only set "hover_data" on first trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the three stock price data as samples, to use data other than the specified y-axis values, there is a custom data feature. In this case, a data frame was specified and the display template format was combined in html format. Since we specified the closing price as the y-axis, we used the other initial price, high price, low price, and volume as hover data.

```
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

aapl = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2022-04-01")
tsla = yf.download("TSLA", start="2021-01-01", end="2022-04-01")
goog = yf.download("GOOG", start="2021-01-01", end="2022-04-01")

fig  = go.Figure()

common_template = ('Open: %{customdata[0]:.2f}<br>' +
'High: %{customdata[1]:.2f}<br>' +
'Low: %{customdata[2]:.2f}<br>' +
'Adj Close: %{customdata[4]:.2f}<br>' +
'Volume: %{customdata[5]}')

    
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=aapl.index, y=aapl['Close'],
             name="AAPL", customdata=aapl,
             hovertemplate=common_template
            )
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=tsla.index, y=tsla['Close'],
             name="TSLA", customdata=tsla,
             hovertemplate=common_template
            )
)
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=goog.index, y=goog['Close'],
             name="GOOG", customdata=goog,
             hovertemplate=common_template
            )
)

fig.update_xaxes(
rangeslider_visible=True,
rangeselector=dict(
    buttons=list([
        dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
        dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
        dict(step="all")
    ])
)
)

fig.show()
```

[image]